# How to implement a event registrator which returns a winrt::event_revoker for a custom type in C++/WinRT, WinUI 3

Tags: c++, event-handling, c++-winrt

I'm trying to add an overload to my `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation for a custom type.

The base implementation for `winrt::event_token` is straight forward:

cpp:

```
winrt::event_token MyType::PropertyChanged(winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler const& handler)
{
    return propertyChanged_.add(handler);
}
void MyType::PropertyChanged(winrt::event_token const& token)
{
    propertyChanged_.remove(token);
}
```

h:

```
winrt::event_token PropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventHandler const& value);
void PropertyChanged(winrt::event_token const& token);
winrt::event<PropertyChangedEventHandler> propertyChanged_;
```

where `MyType` is a vanilla `runtimeclass`

idl:

```
namespace Test {
    [bindable][default_interface]
    runtimeclass MyType : Microsoft.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged
```

h:

```
namespace winrt::Test::implementation {
struct MyType : MyTypeT<MyType>
```

What i naively tried is to add a

```
int32_t unregisterPropertyChanged(winrt::event_token token);
```

to the header, typedef a revoker type there

```
using PropertyChanged_revoker = winrt::event_revoker<MyType>;
```

and implement the adder like this:

```
MyType::PropertyChanged_revoker MyType::PropertyChanged(auto_revoke_t, winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler const& handler)
{
    return PropertyChanged_revoker(get_weak(), &MyType::unregisterPropertyChanged, propertyChanged_.add(handler));
}
```

but it's not that easy and msvc complains about [use_make_function_to_create_this_object](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/blob/380cb8f773e1b9da8d947f6567eeaac401e0c33c/strings/base_implements.h#L871)  where the instantiation causing this [is here](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/blob/51ec25ce5c657048fa552f3054d7427137c9d9ea/strings/base_events.h#L59).

I couldn't find any examples and google or msdn weren't really helpful.

Since i'm not crossing abi boundaries i might be able to roll my own implementation which works around this but that feels wrong. Is there a canonical and no that involved way to do this? How to use `winrt::event_revoker`?

My goal is to put the revoker instances in a `std::vector`.

**EDIT** (the hacky workaround):

*roll my own implementation which works around this* worked; i copied the [winrt event_revoker template](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/blob/51ec25ce5c657048fa552f3054d7427137c9d9ea/strings/base_events.h#L59) and changed its `revoke` method from

```
void revoke() noexcept
{
    if (I object = std::exchange(m_object, {}).get())
    {
        ((*reinterpret_cast<impl::abi_t<I>**>(&object))->*(m_method))(m_token);
    }
}
```

to

```
void revoke() noexcept
{
    if (m_object.get() && m_object.get().get())
    {
        auto p = m_object.get().get();
        m_object = {};
        (p->*(m_method))(m_token);
    }
}
```

but it feels wrong.

Comment: Sample code is provided here: [Revoke a registered delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/handle-events#revoke-a-registered-delegate).

Comment: @IInspectable I think i don't get it. This doesn't show how to implement a registrar which returns a `event_revoker` for a custom type; the sample shows f.e. how to register for a winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Button click using the existing `winrt::event_revoker<winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives::IButtonBase>` type. I'm trying to use a custom type `using PropertyChanged_revoker = winrt::event_revoker<MyType>` and create a event registrar which returns such a revoker.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. I'll have a look when I find a bit of spare time.